# Is there a way to snap the brush to the guidelines in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, grids, brush, snapping

In Adobe Illustrator CS5, is there a way to snap the brush to the guidelines?

This is the effect I'm aiming to create:

[image]

I have created my grid and now I want my brush to align or snap to the guidelines, it is possible?

Now this is want I really want to do:

[image]

This the effect I want to create using the pressure of my pen tablet, with the help of the guidelines.

[image]

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? I think I understand your question, but the image you post confuzzles me -- it doesn't seem to be related to your question at all?

Comment: re: your edit: you'll want to follow @Scott's advice and draw paths and assign a stroke to them. At least, that's how you'd achieve what you're posting.

Answer (score 1):

That image is doing nothing but confusing me. Not sure how it relates to anything, however.....

Draw your path with the **Pen Tool**. It *will* snap to guides.

When the path is drawn, select it and click the brush you want to use. The brush will be applied to the path.

As for standard brushes, no. They won't snap to guides. The freeform drawing tools (Brush, Pencil, Blob Brush) are not designed to snap to anything to keep them "freeform". You can always expand brush strokes so they become shapes, and then snap those shapes to a guide. Of course, you can't easily alter the "flow" of shapes the way you can the spine of a brush stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Command-U (mac) will turn on "Smart Guides". Not sure for PC, perhaps cntrl U?  It will snap to different items you configure (guidelines being an option) in the same menu item where you turn guides on and off.

[image: Turn on "Smart Guides" under "View"]

You can configure the objects to snap to in the Preferences -> Smart Guides tab.

[image: Smart Guide Configuration]

If you want to snap with the brush, you can simply draw the lines with the pen tool, and then select those lines and assign a brush stoke to them.